# Keep getting "CryptographicException : Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." errors with AES CBC encryption even with padding

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core, aes, encryption-symmetric

I've reviewed the other posts on this subject but can't seem to figure out my mistake with this.  I'm trying to stream encrypt files with AES CBC (later I will do the others).  I know I need padding with CBC and have that configured.  However I keep getting the error same error.

```
 Message: 
 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
     Stack Trace: 
  UniversalCryptoDecryptor.DepadBlock(Byte[] block, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
  UniversalCryptoDecryptor.UncheckedTransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
  UniversalCryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
  CryptoStream.ReadAsyncCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean useAsync)
  CryptoStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
  EncryptionFunctions.AESDecryptCBC(String encryptedFile, String plainTextFile, Byte[] key, Byte[] iv, Int32 blockSize, Int32 bufferSize) line 82
  EncryptionFunctionsUnitTests.TestEncryptAndDecryptFiles() line 39
```

I've tried various changes such as different types of padding, but the best I get is some type of junk output.  The encryption appears to work fine, though I can't really tell it's output garage data as it appears like a bunch of Chinese characters.  The input file is just 3 KB of wikipedia text I'm using for testing.

These are the two functions I'm using for the encryption and decryption.

```
 public static void AESEncryptCBC(string plainTextFile, string encryptedFile, byte[] key, byte[] iv, int bufferSize = 65536)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStreamOutput = new FileStream(encryptedFile, FileMode.Create)) {
            using (FileStream fileStreamInput = new FileStream(plainTextFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aes.Key = key;
                    aes.KeySize = key.Length*8; // Keysize is in bits, bytes to bits conversion
                    aes.BlockSize = 128; // bits
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    aes.IV = iv;
                    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStreamOutput, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        int read;
                        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                        while ((read = fileStreamInput.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void AESDecryptCBC(string encryptedFile, string plainTextFile, byte[] key, byte[] iv, int bufferSize = 65536)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStreamOutput = new FileStream(plainTextFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (FileStream fileStreamInput = new FileStream(encryptedFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aes.Key = key;
                    aes.KeySize = key.Length * 8; // Keysize is in bits, bytes to bits conversion
                    aes.BlockSize = 128; // bits
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    aes.IV = iv;
                    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStreamInput, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        int read;
                        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                        while ((read = cryptoStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            fileStreamOutput.Write(readBuffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My unit test method that's calling them.  Don't mind the random number generator, I'm using a hash function for a password later, this is to ensure I have the right size key.

```
 public void TestEncryptAndDecryptFiles()
    {
        string outFile = "out.txt";
        string outFile2 = "out2.txt";

        byte[] salt = new byte[128];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(salt);

        int numberOfBits = 256;
        int blockSize = 128;
        byte[] key = new byte[numberOfBits / 8];
        byte[] iv = new byte[blockSize /8];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(key);
        RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(iv);
        EncryptionFunctions.AESEncryptCBC(SampleText, outFile, key, iv);
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(outFile));

        EncryptionFunctions.AESDecryptCBC(outFile, outFile2, key, iv);
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(outFile2));
        Assert.AreEqual(HashFunctions.Md5(SampleText), HashFunctions.Md5(outFile2));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the KeySize property it makes a new key. When you set the Key property it updates KeySize to match what was set.

You don’t need to set both of them, and since you set KeySize second in both encrypt and decrypt you are encrypting with a random key and decrypting with a different random one.

Calling `CreateEncryptor(key, iv)` solves this by not re-reading the properties that no longer matter.

Comment: That's really annoying then.  Modifying the keysize making a new key is not in any documentation on the Microsoft website for the AES class.  Since it's a property I would not expect modifying one property to reinitialize another.

Comment: @dxk3355 [AesCryptoServiceProvider.KeySize - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.keysize?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) does mention it, but it's not specific to that class.  The behavior comes from [SymmetricAlgorithm.KeySize](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives/System/Security/Cryptography/SymmetricAlgorithm.cs,b0986bbe2e716b70), which erases the key value (making the next property get call `GenerateKey` implicitly).

Comment: @dxk3355 And now SymmetricAlgorithm.KeySize says it, too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.keysize?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but thanks for updating the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out, I needed to change my code to use `aes.CreateEncryptor(key,iv)`.  I finally found that calling `CreateEncryptor()` or `CreateEncryptor(null, null)` automatically generates both an initialization vector and a key which overwrote the ones I set with the `aes.key` and `aes.iv` sets.  Kind of stupid I can set those and then get it overwritten with a function that isn't obviously going to do that. Maybe it's a bug since the one page does say "Creates a symmetric encryptor object with the current Key property and initialization vector (IV)."  It's not doing this based on the code I had previously.

Anyways I found this on 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.generateiv?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_SymmetricAlgorithm_GenerateIV